# GRUB bootloader is not loading at startup

Tags: grub2, bootloader

Please help. Right now I'm using Windows 7 but I want to switch to Linux. So first I tried to install Zorin OS. I successfully installed it by following steps: made live USB, install on free deleted partition (ext4) which is of 45 GB, it got installed successfully,then I restart my PC as per the command. After restarting the GRUB bootloader menu does not appeared and regular Windows got loaded. Then I tried to install another OS, Elementary OS Luna, but the same thing happened again. Please help me out. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you choose to install along side windows or did you choose `something else` option?

Comment: While Zorin and Elementary are derivatives of Ubuntu, they are not officially supported derivatives and questions for them are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. Could you try with Ubuntu (or one of its official flavours like Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.) and modify the question with details pertaining to that attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is GRUB installed to boot-sector of Linux partition (sda5, for example), or to MBR (first sector of physical drive = sda)?

In the first case, GRUB never gets control from MBR.

It seems that [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) is what you need.

Take look to the official Ubuntu documentation, if you want to get more knowledge about that:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Master_Boot_Record_and_Boot_Manager

Comment: Thank you very much.. I'll try this fix and let you know.